# XAML - Way to find which button is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, button, dynamic

I am developing Windows Store App.

I am loading XAML code dynamically from C# code behind file. So, I could not add click event to buttons.

Is there any way to get to know which button is clicked using button names with out the click event?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) patterns for WPF development. The click event handler is outdated Windows Forms programming. In WPF, the command pattern is represented by the [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) interface. Each button has a Command property where you can bind a command object.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading XAML code dynamically? You can load XAML dynamically, locate all button instances, and add event listeners for "Tapped" event.

```
var grid = Xaml.LoadXaml("<Grid><Button x:Name='BLAH' /><Button x:Name='BLAH2'></Grid");
foreach(var button in VisualHelper.FindVIsualCHildren<Button>(grid))
  button.Tapped += delegate(object sender, TappedEventArgs a) 
  { 
        var btn = sender as BUtton; 
   }
```

You can find useful stuff from this toolkit: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am adding Xaml code dynamically like this. UIElement tree = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xaml); 
QRGrid.Children.Add(tree);  Can I use this code for Clicked event also?

Comment: Yes. It can be used for any event.